# ArcGIS "Zoom to layer" scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, analysis, table

I'd like to quickly inspect the features in a feature class by double clicking the row in the table view and looking at the surrounding base layer.

This works, but the feature fills the screen, so I have to zoom out for each feature I inspect.

Is there a way to set the zoom layer, or another method for quickly inspecting the area around many features in a feature class?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also a button "Pan to selected features", which will not change zoom level, but still center the selected feature. I think you'll have to add it to the toolbar yourself through Customize --> Customize mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Data Driven Pages to quickly loop through each feature of your feature class.  Within the settings you can set up what % you want to zoom to - i.e. 100% will have the feature fill the screen, but you might want to try something like 150%.  This tool, although designed to make maps, is also useful for inspecting features quickly.

Comment: Perfect! That was easier than I expected!  For anyone else: you enable data driven pages with customize>toolbars>data driven pages.  Once you click the icon to setup you have arrows you can use to move though the features.